# How can I check if a folder exists in a docker?

Tags: bash, docker

I want to check if a folder exists in a docker then in a bash script act according to the answer:

```
toto = docker exec -it symfony sh -c " test -d imports && echo '1' "
if [[ "$toto" == '1' ]]; then
echo "il exists"
fi
```

Comment: (This seems like a slightly odd workflow to me; I'd normally expect the container's filesystem layout to be basically fixed in the `Dockerfile`, and for that to be totally hidden from the host.  When would the container only maybe have the directory?  How would the host behave differently?)

Comment: it's for a bash script that actually updates postgres

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just run the command inside docker container.

```
if docker exec symfony test -d imports; then
    echo "il exists"
fi
if docker exec symfony [ -d imports ]; then
    echo "il exists"
fi
```

Your code has many problems. Check your script with shellcheck. Consider reading: [How do I set a variable to the output of a command in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651437/how-do-i-set-a-variable-to-the-output-of-a-command-in-bash)